# How can I make invisible or visible some item on the print menu depending on its state in Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, report, odoo, odoo-10

I want the report only appear if the state is only in 'transfer' and make it invisible in all state except 'transfer' state. I try the attributes menu and set it to false like menu = "False" but it doesn't appear also in 'transfer' state. Is any attributes that make the report hide depends on its state? the attrs doesn't work. Is any?

Here is my code.

```
<report
        id="handover_info_rep"
        header="False"
        menu="False"
        model="asset.management.handover"
        string="Handover issuance receipt"
        name="etsi_asset.handover_info_temp"
        file="etsi_asset.handover_info_temp"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        paperformat="paperformat_handover"
    />
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Use button for this

Comment: Okay sir. I have no choice. I think it's not possible to hide and make it visible that print report. Anw thanks

Comment: Yes you cannot because that same menu will show in tree view when you select more than one record how odoo will know ef he have to show the menu or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in a simple way. You can use `menu="False"` or `menu="True"` whether if you want to show the item or not in the print menu, without condition.

#### First approach

You can add some condition in the `render_html` method, in order to validate if the selected records are in the right state:

```
@api.multi
def render_html(self, data=None):
    report_obj = self.env['report']
    report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('etsi_asset.handover_info_temp')

    model_obj = self.env[self.env.context["active_model"]].browse(self.env.context["active_ids"]
    # or >> model_obj = self.env['model.name'].browse(self._ids)

    for record in model_obj:
        if record.state == 'some_state':
            raise ValidationError(
                _('This record cannot be printed in that state.')
            )

    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self._ids,
        'doc_model': report.model,
        'docs': self,
    }
    return report_obj.render('etsi_asset.handover_info_temp', docargs)
```

#### Second approach

You can create a button with the `attrs` attribute. You can add this button on the tree view or on the form view:

```xml
<button name="%(your_module.handover_info_rep)d"
    string="Report name"
    type="action"
    attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '=', 'some_state')]}"/>
```